# How exactly work the Spring RowMapper interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts about how Spring handle the JDBC queries:

So I know that I can obtain data from my DB tables in various ways depending on the type of data that I expect to obtain:

1) Query for **simple type** (as an int, a long or a String): I use the **queryForObject()** method of the **jdbcTemplate** class, something like it:

```
String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM T_REWARD";
int rowsNumber = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
```

So to obtain a simple object as an int value I use the **queryForObject()** method passing to it the **sql stattment** and the object type of I expect to receive in output from the method.

Ok, this is pretty simple and I think that it is ok.

2) Query for an **entire table row** putted into a **Map** object: so if I need no a single value (that could be into a single column of a specific row of a table or something like the preovious example) I can use the **queryForMap(..)** and the **queryForList()** methods, in these way:

2.1) **queryForMap()**: I use it if I expect a **single row** putted into a **single Map object** where each columns value is mapped into a  of my Map, something like:

```
String sql = "select * from T_REWARD where CONFIRMATION_NUMBER = ?";
Map<String, Object> values = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql,confirmation.getConfirmationNumber());
```

2.2) **queryForList()**: I use it if I expect more rows as output of my query. So I will obtain a **list of Map objects** where each Map object represent a specific row of the query output. Something like it:

```
String sql = “select * from PERSON”;
return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
```

I think that also this is pretty clear.

Then I can map a **ResultSet** into a **domain object** using JdbcTemplate and this is not so clear for me.

Reading the documentation is told that JdbcTemplate supports this using a **callback approach**. What exactly meand this **callback approach** ?

I know that Spring provides a **RowMapper interface** for **mapping a single row of a ResultSet to an object**:

```
public interface RowMapper<T> {
    T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
    throws SQLException;
}
```

and I have the following example compoese by this method that use a new RestaurandRowMapper object as returned object of a **queryForObject()** method:

```
public Restaurant findByMerchantNumber(String merchantNumber) {
    String sql = "select MERCHANT_NUMBER, NAME, BENEFIT_PERCENTAGE, BENEFIT_AVAILABILITY_POLICY from T_RESTAURANT where MERCHANT_NUMBER = ?";

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new RestaurantRowMapper(), merchantNumber);
```

and this **inner class**:

```
class RestaurantRowMapper implements RowMapper<Restaurant> {
    public Restaurant mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        return mapRestaurant(rs);
    }
}
```

that use this private method to create the mapping:

```
private Restaurant mapRestaurant(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    // get the row column data
    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
    String number = rs.getString("MERCHANT_NUMBER");
    Percentage benefitPercentage = Percentage.valueOf(rs.getString("BENEFIT_PERCENTAGE"));
    // map to the object
    Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant(number, name);
    restaurant.setBenefitPercentage(benefitPercentage);
    restaurant.setBenefitAvailabilityPolicy(mapBenefitAvailabilityPolicy(rs));
    return restaurant;
}
```

So I have some difficulties to understand how exactly work all this stuff.

My main doubt is the following one: I know that using the **queryForObject()** method I pass to it, as input parameter, the type of the object that I expect as output (for example an Interger or a Long).

If I expect to obtain a domain object that represent an entire row of a table (for example a row of the **Restaurant table** mapped into a **Restaurand object) I'm thinking that I should use this object (as the Restaurant object) but in the previous example I use the **row mapper object** instead the **domain object**:

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new RestaurantRowMapper(), merchantNumber);
```

This inner class contain only the **mapRow()** method that return the expected **domain object**

```
class RestaurantRowMapper implements RowMapper<Restaurant> {
    public Restaurant mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        return mapRestaurant(rs);
    }
}
```

So I think that Spring automatically call the **mapRow()** method that return the **Restaurand domain object** that is automatically replaced into the queryForObject() method, or something like this. But I am not so sure about it exactly work.

What am I missing? Can you explain me what exactly happen in the backstage?

Tnx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `queryForObject` method looks like this:

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, Object... args) throws DataAccessException {
    List<T> results = query(sql, args, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<T>(rowMapper, 1));
    return DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(results);
}
```

The `queryForObject`-method internally invokes the method `query` on the `JdbcTemplate` object. The `query`-method is defined as:

```
public <T> T query(
        PreparedStatementCreator psc, final PreparedStatementSetter pss, final ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
        throws DataAccessException;
```

As you can see, a `ResultSetExtractor<T>` is passed to the `query`-method and Spring conveniently converts your `RowMapper<T>` to an object of type `new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<T>(rowMapper, 1)`. The `RowMapperResultSetExtractor` is the object that holds the key to the magic. When the object is invoked it iterates all rows as per this snippet:

```
public List<T> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<T> results = (this.rowsExpected > 0 ? new ArrayList<T>(this.rowsExpected) : new ArrayList<T>());
    int rowNum = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        results.add(this.rowMapper.mapRow(rs, rowNum++));
    }
    return results;
}
```

So, your original `RowMapper` is the callback that is called for each row. Furthermore, as you can see here your `RowMapper` is invoked for all matching results and the `Restaurant`-object that you created is added to the result list. However, since you query for only **one** object the following statement is finally used to return your single `Restaurant` object.

```
        return DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(results);
```

So, to sum up: `JdbcTempalte` implementes the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (which is similar to the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)). And by providing a *Strategy interface* (the `RowMapper`) you can let `JdbcTemplate` do the heavy lifting for you (handling exceptions, connections etc). The `RowMapper` maps each hit as a POJO (the `Restaurant`) and all hits are collected to a `List`. The method `queryForObject` then takes the first row from that `List` and returns it to the caller. The return value is based on the generic type of the `RowMapper` which in your case is `Restaurant`.

Answer (score 1):

Use jdbcTemplate.queryForObject it will resolve your problem like this

```
public YourPojo getDatabaseDetails(int masterId) {

    sql = "Select * FROM <table_name> where ID=?";
    YourPojo pojo = (YourPojo) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,
            new Object[] { masterId }, new RowMapper<YourPojo>() {
                @Override
                public <YourPojo> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                        throws SQLException {
                    YourPojo pojo2 = new YourPojo();
                    pojo2.setAccountId(rs.getString("AccountId"));
                    pojo2.setAccountName(rs.getString("AccountName"));
                    pojo2.setAccountCRN(rs.getString("AccountCRN"));
                    pojo2.setAccountStatus(rs.getString("AccountStatus"));
                    return pojo2;
                }
            });
    return pojo;
}
```