# Java spring jdbc: Jdbctemplate join query

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I want to retrieve a list of Order objects.
Each Order object may have a list of OrderRows. OrderRows are kept in a separate table. How do I use the query below with Jdbctemplate?

```
"SELECT order_number, itemname, quantity, price FROM orders" +
" LEFT JOIN order_rows ON orders.id = order_rows.order_id" +
" WHERE orders.id = ?"
```

Comment: You read the first element of the resultset and create the Order object and its first OrderRow, that you add to the Order. then you read the subsequent elements of the resultset, and you create an OrderRow for each of them, that you add to the Order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data in List of Map you can us jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(..) method. 
If you need your data in a dto, you need to define a customer Row mapper, refer these posts - [How exactly work the Spring RowMapper interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591847/how-exactly-work-the-spring-rowmapper-interface)